# Action mode does not start for ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionmode, actionmode

When I perform long click on ListView item, action mode does not start.
Implementations for ListView are the same through a project:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);         

listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);              

listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new NutritionMultiChoiceModeListener() { 

    @Override                                                                
    public void deleteSelectedItems() {                                      
        for (int i = 0; i < componentAdapter.getCount(); i++) {              
            if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {                            
                //Some actions                          
            }                                                                
        }                                                                    
    }                                                                        
});
```

NutritionMultiChoiceModeListener is custom MultiChoiceModeListener, that contains abstract method deleteSelectedItems(), that called for deletions.

Here is layout for ListView item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backround_activated"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/component_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/component_grams_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ingredient_grams"
    android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I perform long click, I either press the Button or start editing text.

There is only one such place in project. For other item layouts, that contain only TextViews, everything works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where in your code snippet you are starting the action mode on a long-click.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/LongPress) that demonstrates starting an action mode on a long-click. In there, the list starts in normal mode, but then on a long-click I switch into the multiple-choice-modal mode and check the long-clicked-upon item:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

    return(true);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's work. I still need to figure out, how to make another items selectable, cause for now button and edittext intercept click even in action mode. I believe, I can do it by myself. But I still have a quick question, if you don't mind. Another ListView in project consists of items with TextViews only. And I don't need to set OnItemLongClickListener for that ListView - everything works as it is. That is because TextViews are not "focusable" or something?

Comment: @Shakenbeer: Definitely having focusable widgets in `ListView` rows causes changes in behavior, which is why I try to avoid having focusable widgets in `TextView` rows. :-)